# Another Error Pushing my Repository to Github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, terminal

When I enter into the terminal:

```
Parkers-MacBook-Pro:first_app ppreyer$ git remote add origin git@github.com:ppreyer/first_app.git
Parkers-MacBook-Pro:first_app ppreyer$ git push origin master
```

I get the following error:

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:ppreyer/first_app.git'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

So I went back and entered the following into the terminal and got another error:

```
Parkers-MacBook-Pro:first_app ppreyer$ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/ppreyer/.ssh/first_app/first_app/.git/
Parkers-MacBook-Pro:first_app ppreyer$ git add .
Parkers-MacBook-Pro:first_app ppreyer$ git commit -m
error: switch `m' requires a value
usage: git commit [options] [--] <filepattern>...

    -q, --quiet           suppress summary after successful commit
    -v, --verbose         show diff in commit message template

Commit message options
    -F, --file <file>     read message from file
    --author <author>     override author for commit
    --date <date>         override date for commit
    -m, --message <message>
                          commit message
    -c, --reedit-message <commit>
                          reuse and edit message from specified commit
    -C, --reuse-message <commit>
                          reuse message from specified commit
    --fixup <commit>      use autosquash formatted message to fixup specified commit
    --squash <commit>     use autosquash formatted message to squash specified commit
    --reset-author        the commit is authored by me now (used with -C-c/--amend)
    -s, --signoff         add Signed-off-by:
    -t, --template <file>
                          use specified template file
    -e, --edit            force edit of commit
    --cleanup <default>   how to strip spaces and #comments from message
    --status              include status in commit message template

Commit contents options
    -a, --all             commit all changed files
    -i, --include         add specified files to index for commit
    --interactive         interactively add files
    -o, --only            commit only specified files
    -n, --no-verify       bypass pre-commit hook
    --dry-run             show what would be committed
    --short               show status concisely
    --branch              show branch information
    --porcelain           machine-readable output
    -z, --null            terminate entries with NUL
    --amend               amend previous commit
    --no-post-rewrite     bypass post-rewrite hook
    -u, --untracked-files[=<mode>]
                          show untracked files, optional modes: all, normal, no. (Default: all)
```

What does error: switch `m' requires a value mean?

Comment: Does the repository exists there?

Comment: Is your current branch called master?

Comment: Have you actually committed anything to your local repository?  Without an initial commit there is no `master` branch.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your remote doesn't have a master branch (you probably just created it and it is empty?)

Use one of the following to create the master branch:

```
git push -u origin master
```

or

```
git push origin master:master
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you forgot to add a commit message after the "commit" command.

Correct usage is:

```
$ git commit -m "Initial Commit"
```